# Creating a bucketed column in R with some caveats

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column like so:

```
ID  Reward
1   -99
2   20
3   10
4   45
5   100
6   23
7  -99
```

I want to bucket the Reward column in R. I want 5 buckets. 1 bucket to have ONLY -99. -99 is the only negative number in the data set and needs its own category. And then 4 buckets that bucket the rest of the numbers evenly.

I have code to bucket into 4 buckets.. but I need to do 5 where -99 has its own bucket..:

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(Reward = cut(Reward, breaks = 4),
                     Reward = match(Reward, unique(Reward)) - 1)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just `as.numeric(cut(df$Reward, 5))`?

Comment: But then it'll only have 4 unique values @Maël. But the idea is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Hmisc::cut2`, you can cut evenly by quantiles. You can have four evenly distributed groups (`g = 4`) among the values different from -99, and then one group for values that equals -99.

```r
library(Hmisc)
df$cut[df$Reward != -99] <- cut2(df$Reward[df$Reward != -99], g = 4)
df$cut[df$Reward == -99] <- 0
df                 

  ID Reward cut
1  1    -99   0
2  2     20   1
3  3     10   1
4  4     45   3
5  5    100   4
6  6     23   2
7  7    -99   0
```